# Updating the contents of a CSV file in PHP

Tags: php

I have created a register and recover password form which insert data into my database and also writes to a notepad file in CVS format.
when users register, their information get written to my file but when they recover and change their password, i don't know how to write new information to my file.
i need to seek through my notepad file to find the email of my user and update his/her new password.
imagine this is my CVS file=>

```
meysam,1234,meysam@gmail.com
ali,5050,ali@gmail.com
sarah,sr@,sara@gmail.com
```

if my user named Ali changes his password, how can i write the new password to my file?

Comment: Why are you duplicating effort and using such an awful format for it? You have the database. Just use the database. If you need a backup, use the backup features of your DB. If you ever have some reason to export data to CSV then do it on demand instead of trying to keep it in sync.

Comment: You could consider another approach. If your users are not that many, you can always (using a library for parsing csv files) convert the existing data in Php objects, check the matching user, update and re-write them into the file afresh

Comment: I'm trying to learn so that i need to know how it works.

Comment: @Eenvincible how can turn it into an object?